# How to open Visual Studio 2017 in debug mode with MS Edge instead of IE 11

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a SharePoint hosted add-in project created using VS 2017 (v15.9.26) and want to run & debug the application using Microsoft Edge and NOT the default IE 11.  Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

I know that if I have a "Web App" the option of "Browse with..." comes up as a option on the top FILE menu option... but that option is NOT available in my "SharePoint Add-in" project type.

Thank you.